# Связи HasOne в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь сделать связь вот такого вида:

```
 $this->hasOne(\common\models\MyModel::className(), ['novos_id' => 'novos_id','rooms' => 'rooms','ROUND(a.area,1) = ROUND(b.area,1)'])->alias('b')
```

Но не получается. Нужно как-то запихнуть в связь `'ROUND(a.area,1) = ROUND(b.area,1)'` в ON , но инфы не нашел как это сделать. Может кто сталкивался ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Это комментарий.

1. Второй параметр в hasOne() должен указывать на поля, по которым таблицы связаны. Если хотите добавить дополнительные условия, то используйте where().

Пример из моей модели:

```
public function getFiles()
{
return $this->hasMany(Attachment::classname(),['itemId' => 'id'])
->where(['model' => 'message']);
}
```

2. Укажите структуры этих двух таблиц и что вы хотите этим запросом получить. Так вопрос будет понятнее.
3. Лучше сначала напишите ваш запрос на чистом SQL, а потом переводите на  yii2. Я так делаю, если запрос сложен)

Comment: Да решил left join заюзать , вместо связи. Спасибо за совет)